# Multiple table database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I have a website where I display a list of sports players and their stats. Users can register and create a team of these players where I sum and analyze the team stats. I would like to give each user the ability to "cross out" a player from the list (yet not remove them from the database) and reinstate a player that has been crossed out back to the list if they need to. The players that are crossed out or not crossed out need to be saved in a database so when the user returns to the site their list is saved.

These are the tables I currently have:

```
Players Table (COLS: Name, Team, Position, Stats, etc.)
Users Table (COLS: User ID, Name, Email, etc.)
Teams Table (COlS: User ID, 1, 2, 3, etc.)
```

I'm pretty sure that there is a better way to store the info in the Teams Table where I have a column for user id and then 30 columns (numbered 1-30) where I store the player name and position he was selected for in the cell (in this format Player Name/Position). A team can consist up to 30 players.

I think I would need an "Available Table" that stores which players are crossed out by which users. I'm not sure what is the best way to go about this considering a user can cross out up to 600 players from the list.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm completely new to dealing with databases and I have seem to hit a wall.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207821/how-to-structure-large-mysql-database

Answer (score 1):

You should probably remove the player data from the team table and set up a join table for the players and team data.

So you end up with

```
Teams Table (Cols: ID, User ID, Team Name)
Team_Players Table (Cols: Team_ID, Player_ID, Position, Active)
```

You can then get which players are in which team by running a query on Team_Players and check if they are active or not.

I didn't add an ID field because the join of Team_ID and Player_ID would be unique and could be used as the key for this table.

Comment: Would this Team_Players Table then potentially have a row for each team and each player combination? Would that cause an issue with around 600 players and many users?

Comment: @user1956847 It won't cause any issue in terms of functionality but generally performance for _any_ query decreases as the number of records to query increase. You should also set an index for the `Team_ID` and `Player_ID` columns so that the DB does some amount of lookup optimization for your query on the `Team_Players` table.

Comment: You would only have 30 records per team/user combination based on your specification.

Answer (score 0):

**Read this tutorial**. It is very helpful:

http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=association.php

The design of your database depends on whether a given player can belong to more than one team in the database. If it can, that is a `has and belongs to many` relationship and you would need a linking table, perhaps called `Players_Teams` (always list tables in alpha order). This table could also contain the `crossedOff` column you were talking about.

Using an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like ActiveRecord or Doctrine can greatly reduce the amount of code you need to write to make the management of these relationships somewhat "automatic" in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that tutorial really helped. I think I understand it but I am worried about the the mass amounts of potential records in the Players_Team table. With the crossedOff attribute there could potentially be 600 records per user. Would this create an issue as my number of users increases?

Comment: You can consider denormalization as an alternative (e.g. storing the associated records as json) but it makes stats harder. As long as you are querying by primary key in the code, the data will easily shard as you scale. Also MySQL is plenty capable of handling large tables with the right indexing and caching.